# Can I use Prism 5.0 to make a .NET 4.0 WPF application?

Tags: .net, wpf, prism

In the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx) it provides a note saying

"Note: For .NET 4.0, Silverlight, or Windows Phone 7.x applications use Prism 4.1."

On the Prism 5.0 guide in [system requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405471%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#sec4) it says

"WPF applications built using this guidance require the .NET Framework 4.5"

Does Prism 5.0 contain everything that Prism 4.x contains + new stuff? If so then could I just install Prism 5.0 but follow the guide for Prism 4.1?

Or did they rewrite certain things to depend on .NET 4.5?

Comment: I think it clearly states that .NET Framework 4.5 is required; so the answer is likely no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't use Prism 5.0 with .NET 4.0.

The reason is that the Prism 5.0 code uses some features which are not available in the Framework 4.0.

For example, the [CallerMemberName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=VS.110).aspx) attribute in the [`BindableBase`](https://compositewpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#V5/PrismLibrary/Prism.Mvvm/BindableBase.cs) class.